# Why won't SQLite use my index for order by

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

My Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1, t2
WHERE (t1.ZID=t2.ZCHARACTERID AND t1.ZID IN (1,2,3,4) AND t2.Z_ENT=3)
ORDER BY t2.ZSTROKECOUNT
```

My Indices:

```
CREATE INDEX i1 on t1(ZID);
CREATE INDEX i2 on t2(ZCHARACTERID, Z_ENT, ZSTROKECOUNT);
```

Explain Query Plan

```
selectid    order       from        detail                                                                         
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------------------------------------------------------------  --------------
0           0           1           SEARCH TABLE t1 USING INDEX i1 (ZID=?) (~740 rows)
0           0           0           EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1                                                        
0           1           0           SEARCH TABLE t2 USING INDEX i2 (ZCHARACTERID=? AND Z_ENT=?) (~9 row)
0           0           0           USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

From line 3 of the explain query plan, it says only two indexed columns are used and temp b-tree is used for order by. But from what I understand, I should be able to use i2 for order by as well.

Did I miss anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

because you forgot `FROM` clause

try this way

```
   SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (t1.ZID=t2.ZCHARACTERID AND t1.ZID IN (1,2,3,4) AND t2.Z_ENT=3) ORDER BY t2.ZSTROKECOUNT
```

Answer (score 1):

The index is not ordered by `ZSTROKECOUNT`.

SQLite will use the index for sorting if you do this:

```
DROP INDEX i2;
CREATE INDEX i3 ON t2(ZSTROKECOUNT, ZCHARACTERID, Z_ENT);
```

Comment: Is this NOT using it for the WHERE?

Comment: @cellige `i3` is used to scan the table, so no separate WHERE lookups are done.

Comment: I see, they are already in order, but I would have thought it could skip as it goes as well?

This query is driving me nuts
SELECT Child.lastModifiedDate, Child.path
FROM Folders Child 
JOIN Folders Parent ON Child.folderId = Parent.id
WHERE Parent.path = ''
AND Child.name > ''
ORDER BY Child.name, Child.path

I've tried every combination of INDEXED BY on both the FROMS and can not get it to not use a TEMP BTREE, any ideas?

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.